# Object.entries with forEach to map array of objects returns undefined except when console.log is used

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects that have key value pairs, I want to find a specific key in each object and return the value.

A sample of the Array:

```
filterCounties=[
  {
    "StateName": "Delaware",
    "CountyName": "Kent",
    "FIPS": 10001,
    "Eligibles_2017": 33292,
    "Eligibles_2018": 34938,
    "Penetration_2017": 0.107,
    "Penetration_2018": 0.123
  },
  {
    "StateName": "Delaware",
    "CountyName": "New Castle",
    "FIPS": 10003,
    "Eligibles_2017": 94030,
    "Eligibles_2018": 98080,
    "Penetration_2017": 0.128,
    "Penetration_2018": 0.164
  },
  {
    "StateName": "Delaware",
    "CountyName": "Sussex",
    "FIPS": 10005,
    "Eligibles_2017": 61964,
    "Eligibles_2018": 65990,
    "Penetration_2017": 0.082,
    "Penetration_2018": 0.097
  },
  {
    "StateName": "Delaware",
    "CountyName": "Pending County Designation",
    "FIPS": 10,
    "Eligibles_2017": 9,
    "Eligibles_2018": 0,
    "Penetration_2017": 0,
    "Penetration_2018": 0
  }
]
```

The key I am looking for is Penetration_2018 - I can use the following code and output the values using console.log

```
const mapTest = new Map(
      Object.entries(filterCounties).forEach(([key, value]) =>
        console.log((key, value["Penetration_2018"]))
      )
    );
```

This will output the values: 
[console.log output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EVPO.png)

However if I assign to a variable and then log the variable

```
 const mapTest = new Map(
      Object.entries(filterCounties).forEach(
        ([key, value]) => (key, value["Penetration_2018"])
      )
    );
    console.log(`This is mapTest ${mapTest}`);
```

I get  [object Map] with no values - I thought that when using an arrow function, return was implicit?

Image of output - with or without String concatenation  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAHeL.png)

I ultimately want to extract these values to assign them to the Y axis of a Victory BarChart. Thanks for any insight / guidance.

Comment: Thanks for such a  quick response - I had tried that with the same result - just tried again - will edit the post to show an image of output.

Comment: `forEach()` never provides a return, unless you consider `undefined` a return. Use `map()` it always provides a return.

Comment: See [javascript - Why is .forEach returning undefined? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53296250/why-is-foreach-returning-undefined) instead if you want to return the object after **mutating** the elements of the **original** object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.forEach` does not return a value or an array. Try using `.map` instead. Also, you don't need a Javascript `Map` in this case (it can't have repeated keys), considering furthermore that Victory BarChart seems to take an `Array` as data (not a `Map`).

This is my suggested change:

```
const mapTest = filterCounties.map(
  element => ({'Penetration_2018': element['Penetration_2018']})
)
```

Answer (score 9):

Several issues:

- `forEach` always returns `undefined`. You need to use `map` instead.
- `(key, value["Penetration_2018"])` is not a tuple, but a comma operator expression and results in the value of `value["Penetration_2018"]`. Use square bracket notation instead.
- A `Map` has no useful representation when cast to string. You need to turn it to an array or something else to get a more useful string representation:

Code:

```
const mapTest = new Map(
    Object.entries(filterCounties).map(
        ([key, value]) => [key, value["Penetration_2018"]]
    )
);
console.log(`This is mapTest ${JSON.stringify([...mapTest])}`);
```

With arrays it is more conventional to just apply `map` directly on the array, and it is a mystery why you would need a Map anyway. If you want the unique values, then use a Set:

```
const uniques = [...new Set(filterCounties.map(value => value["Penetration_2018"]))];
console.log(`This is uniques: ${uniques}`);
```

Comment: Thank you so much @trincot for the detailed explanations - really appreciate it. I apologize for not being more thorough in my explanation - the array has approximately 3000 counties, many duplicate Penetration values when taken alone - hence Set not being viable in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

`Object.entries` is pretty useless on an array. If necessary, you'd use the array `entries` method.

> I thought that when using an arrow function, return was implicit?

An arrow function with a concise body implicitly returns the expression value, yes. However, in your first example, `console.log` does not return anything, and in both examples, `forEach` returns nothing. And in your second example, you use the comma operator for some kind of "tuple" notation while the `Map` constructor requires arrays.

Instead of trying to use "*forEach to map array of objects*", you should use the `map` method to map an array of objects!

```
const mapTest = new Map(filterCounties.map((value, key) => [key, value.Penetration_2018]));
console.log('This is mapTest:', mapTest);
```

Comment: Thank you @Bergi - appreciate it - I see my issue, thanks for taking the time to explain.