# Why is .forEach returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I know there already are multiple questions to this topic https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+return+forEach+undefined but none of this seemed to help me out.

So I have the following data:

```
 const testsMap = {
            0: ["just", "test"],
            1: ["bla", "asdf"]
        }

 const testArray = [{
    id: "1",
    segments: null,
    tests: [{
            id: "1",
            segments: "1"
        },
        {
            id: "2",
            segments: "0"
        }
    ]
},
{
    id: "2",
    segments: "1",
    tutorials: [{
            id: "1",
            segments: "1"
        },
        {
            id: "2",
            segments: "0"
        }
    ]
}];
```

What I want to achieve with the output *without* using `.map()` or `.reduce` since I do not want a new array, I just want to overwrite the existing one, is the following:

```
[{
    display: true,
    id: "1",
    segments: null,
    tests: [{
            display: true,
            id: "1",
            segments: "1",
            newSegments: ["bla", "asdf"]
        },
        {
            display: true,
            id: "2",
            segments: "0",
            newSegments: ["just", "test"]
        }
    ]
},
{
    display: false,
    id: "2",
    segments: "1",
    tutorials: [{
            id: "1",
            segments: "1"
        },
        {
            id: "2",
            segments: "2"
        }
    ]
}];
```

The function I have looks something like this - please note that it has some helper fns which you can ignore - it's just about that the fn returns `undefined`:

```
function SOtest () {
  const returnedValue = testArray.forEach(test => {
    test.newSegments = test.segments ? testsMap[test.segments] : [];
    test.display = helperFn(); // will add true/false to the test prop

    if (test.display) {
      test.tests.map(t => {
        t.newSegments = t.segments ? testsMap[t.segments] : [];
        t.display = helperFn(); // will add true/false to the test prop
      })
    }
    return test;
  })
  return returnedValue;
}
```

Now the `forEach` itself works just fine when executed by itself in the console - but as soon as I want to return it, it equals `undefined`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Because `forEach` does not create a new object. It doesn't have a return value. You could simply `return testArray;` since you are mutating that object.

Comment: Of course you can't return from `forEach`.

Comment: Use `map` instead of `forEach`

Comment: You say you want to change the array in place, which is why you don't want to use `map()`, but then you go ahead and use code that tries to create a new array and return it... also `testArray` is a variable external to `SOtest`, so there's no need to return anything in the first place.

Comment: You missed the part of the documentation/specification, where it simply says "Return value: `undefined`".

Comment: Yeah my bad, went completely in the wrong direction. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`forEach` doesn't return anything. It just loops through elements and while looping you can change element data

And so you can change your function `SOtest` to

```
function SOtest () {
  testArray.forEach(test => {
    test.newSegments = test.segments ? testsMap[test.segments] : [];
    test.display = helperFn(); // will add true/false to the test prop

    if (test.display) {
      test.tests.map(t => {
        t.newSegments = t.segments ? testsMap[t.segments] : [];
        t.display = helperFn(); // will add true/false to the test prop
      })
    }
  })
  return testArray;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [mdn forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

> forEach() executes the callback function once for each array element;
>   unlike map() or reduce() it always returns the value undefined and is
>   not chainable. The typical use case is to execute side effects at the
>   end of a chain.

Answer (score 0):

According to MDN:

.map() returns "A new array with each element being the result of the callback function."

.forEach() returns undefined.

If the code you're looping through is meant to be contiguous, use .map(), otherwise the .forEach() is fine.

Sources:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map