# Turn a for loop into a foreach loop not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, foreach, conditional-operator

I am trying to turn a `for` loop into a `forEach` loop, but it doesn't seem to be working...

Here is my code:

```js
const townDataURL = "[some link I probably can't disclose...]"
const towns2get = [
    "Preston",
    "Fish Haven",
    "Soda Springs"
]

fetch(townDataURL)
    .then((response) => {
        return response.json()
    })
    .then((jsonData) => {
        const towns = jsonData["towns"].filter((item) => {
            // for (let i = 0; i<towns2get.length; i++) {
            //     if (item.name == towns2get[i]) {
            //         return item
            //     }
            // }
            return (towns2get.forEach(elem => {
                return ( (item.name == elem) ? (item) : "Hello?" )
            }))
        })
        console.log(towns)
    })
```

When I have the commented code run it gives me this:

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {name: "Fish Haven", photo: "fishhaven.jpg", motto: "This is Fish Heaven.", yearFounded: 1864, currentPopulation: 501, …}
1: {name: "Preston", photo: "preston.jpg", motto: "Home of Napoleon Dynamite.", yearFounded: 1866, currentPopulation: 5204, …}
2: {name: "Soda Springs", photo: "sodasprings.jpg", motto: "Historic Oregon Trail Oasis. The Soda is on Us.", yearFounded: 1858, currentPopulation: 2985, …}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Which is exactly what I want, but I want to simplify my code... what I have now gives me this:

```
[]
length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I've done some debugging and I know that my conditional statement with the ternary operator works fine, and it is returning a value... but I can't seem to figure out why it isn't returning it back to the `filter` method...

Does it not work this way? Or do I have to somehow put the `forEach` with the `filter`?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) returns `undefined` -- I would use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to achieve what I think you want...

Comment: `.forEach()` doesn't return anything, so your `.filter()` callback returns `undefined`, a falsey value, for each element. Use `.filter(town => towns2get.includes(town.name))`

Comment: Oh... I forgot that forEach doesn't return... Thanks! I will try that!

Comment: You possibly will need to use the index within `map`... That is the second argument of the callback you will provide: `towns2get.map((item,index){...}` ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is .forEach returning undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53296250/why-is-foreach-returning-undefined)

Comment: @ChrisG - Thanks again! That was the answer I needed!

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette - No, that doesn't answer my question... that just tells me why `.forEach()` returns undefined... which is helpful, but not the answer... Thanks for sharing!

Comment: You're welcome, but it's still a dupe: [How do I check if an array includes a value in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-a-value-in-javascript) (the for loop business is unrelated; turning into a forEach loop was not the solution to the actual problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cris G gave me the answer:

> `.forEach()` doesn't return anything, so your `.filter()` callback returns `undefined`, a falsey value, for each element. Use `filter(item => towns2get.includes(item.name))` – [Chris G](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5734311/chris-g)

So the code should then be:

```js
const townDataURL = "[some link I probably can't disclose...]"
const towns2get = [
    "Preston",
    "Fish Haven",
    "Soda Springs"
]

fetch(townDataURL)
    .then((response) => {
        return response.json()
    })
    .then((jsonData) => {
        const towns = jsonData["towns"].filter(item => towns2get.includes(item.name))
        console.log(towns)
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

The better way here is to use the .includes function inside the filter method

```
const townDataURL = "[some link I probably can't disclose...]"
const towns2get = [
    "Preston",
    "Fish Haven",
    "Soda Springs"
]

fetch(townDataURL)
    .then((response) => {
        return response.json()
    })
    .then((jsonData) => {
        const towns = jsonData["towns"].filter((item) => {
            if(towns2get.includes(item.name) > -1) return true;
            else return false;
        })
        console.log(towns)
    })
```

Comment: I think OP does not want to filter the array, but wants to replace a non-matching value with something else ("Hello?" in the example)

Comment: I guess he used it to temporarily check the condition...but it's not intended in his expected output

Comment: mmm... Maybe! ;)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette - That was just me testing to see if it was doing _anything_...  Amaarshall Yaswankar is right, I did not want it in my output.

Comment: @AmaarshallYaswankar - That answer is nearly what I got from someone else... though theirs was slightly more condensed... thank you for that answer, though, it helped me understand it better!

Comment: @AmaarshallYaswankar - One thing that you could do to simplify the code is do `return (towns2get.includes(item.name) > -1)` instead of the `if(...) return true  else return false`...