# Why this forEach mapping is undefined?

Tags: javascript

Why the result for this `forEach` mapping is undefined?

```
const list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
const result = list.forEach(a => a % 2 === 0 ? a : -a);
console.log(result); // console prints undefined
```

Comment: For each isn't map. It's good that you thought to return from foreach anyway rather than mutate a variable outside the loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Object.entries with forEach to map array of objects returns undefined except when console.log is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48747444/object-entries-with-foreach-to-map-array-of-objects-returns-undefined-except-whe)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) does not return anything. So you are getting undefined. In this case you can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which will return an array

```js
const list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
const result = list.map(a => a % 2 === 0 ? a : -a);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

`forEach` runs an action for each member on the list, if you want a new list with values based on the expression, you should use `map`

Answer (score 0):

Foreach doesnt collect results of the function you pass it, you need to use `map` for that!

```js
const list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
const result = list.map(a => a % 2 === 0 ? a : -a);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because the forEach doesn't return a new object, then it is undefined. If you want a return you should use .map.

Answer (score 0):

I would add that [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is used to perform a function *that does return something* on each item in an array, so you could do the following:

```
const list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
const result = list.forEach(a => console.log(a % 2 === 0 ? a : -a));
```

however if you need a new array with the computed results, `map` is the better solution.